# How to Access Database/content providers by multiple processes in android.?

Tags: multiprocessing, android-contentprovider

First Thanks for looking into my problem,
I have a problem with accessing android ContentProviders using multiple process.

Problem is like this, I have created a ContentProvider class which will create database.
Now for this database i am writing something by using first process and this one is Synchronized process,
second thing, i have second process which will read the data from that ContentProvider in the same time.
I can't stop the second process until the first process completes, because i need some data before putting into the ContentProvider.,

How to over come this, need some help... 
Thanks once again.